# DataReport data from multi tables help required

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I am facing a problem that I have to show database results from 3 different tables on a single report these three tables have are used for different purposes and want to show their headings details separately. I am using VB6, MS Access and designing this report in **DataReport** a common feature for this.

> **Table1** is for Menu Details

Having following fields: Bill_ID, Menu Type, Cost

> **Table2** is for Services Details:

Having following fields: Bill_ID, Service Name, Cost

> **Table3** is for Extra Details:

Having following fields: Bill_ID, Description, Cost
Now structure I want to is like this using common Bill ID, and want to show the headings for each table and then details of each table one by one like this

```
Bill ID: 1234567890

Menu Details
+-----------+--------+
| Menu Type | Amount |
+-----------+--------+
| Prod1     |    100 |
| Prod2     |     60 |
| Prod3     |     75 |
+-----------+--------+

Service Details
+--------------+------+
| Service Name | Cost |
+--------------+------+
| Service1     |   15 |
| Service2     |   17 |
+--------------+------+

Extra Details
+-------------+------+
| Description | Cost |
+-------------+------+
| Extra1      |   11 |
| Extra2      |   12 |
+-------------+------+

Total Amount: $xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I used Data Reports in VB6, but I would have created 3 sub reports from 3 different tables and linked the subreports using the Biil_ID after embedding them into the main report.

> I tried posting this as a comment, but I dont have enough reputation to post a comment and hence I have posted this as an answer